# Is there way to make one column wider than others?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to make one series column in column graph twice wider that the others, is there any way to achieve this?

I've tried to create two columns in group and set border to 0, but then I had to set border of other columns twice big, which is causing inconsistent border width in export and different resolutions.
Also haven't found a way to change border property of column only to left/right side.

There's picture of how my currently graph looks: https://image.prntscr.com/image/4wbyWB2pQIyVtPWAF3HKkA.png
You can see that borders aren't consistent and width of border is not same at different resolutions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pointWidth` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointWidth)) for this purpose like this:

```
....
series: [{
  data: [{
    name: 'Point 1',
    y: 1,
    pointWidth:100
  },
...
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/ro76yL1p/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `render` event and double the width of the point graphic element:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        render: function() {
            var point = this.series[0].points[1];

            point.graphic.attr({
                width: point.pointWidth * 2
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ufqox26n/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr